# Dropdown jquery method post form not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem, I added a dropdown ddslick on a page only that the post method does not work.

This is a test page: see you.

```
<?php 
$values=$_POST['list'];
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
       $i="<span style='font-color:red;font-weight:bold'>";$s="</span>";
       echo $i;
       echo $options[$value];
       echo $values;
       echo $s;
   }
}
?>
<center><h2>This is a page to test the drop down</h2>
<form method='post'>
<select id="demo-htmlselect-basic"name="list">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">Part 1</option>
  <option value="2">Part 2</option>
  <option value="3">Part 3</option>
</select><br/><br/>
<input type="submit"name="submit"id="submit"value="Submit"/>
</form>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="//healtend.it/uploads/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="//healtend.it/uploads/jquery.ddslicksd.min.js"></script>
```

Waiting for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and indent your code.

Comment: where is your jquery code?

Answer (score 0):

You missed write the ";" at the last of one echo.

> echo $s;

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
   $i="<span style='font-color:red;font-weight:bold'>";$s="</span>";
   echo $i;
   echo $options[$value];
   echo $values;
   echo $s;
}
```

Comment: Its not an issue its typo mistake from questioner. Read question : Dropdown jquery method post form not working

Comment: It is not the problem. You must see the part html.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `name="list"` in your `jquery.ddslicksd.min.js` file, Please modify your code

`http://healtend.it/uploads/jquery.ddslicksd.min.js`

add

`name="list"` to `<input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" />` line.

And for php + HTML code like below:

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $values = $_POST['list'];
        $i="<span style='font-color:red;font-weight:bold'>";
        $s="</span>";
        echo $i;
        echo $values;
        echo $s;

    }
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <center>
            <h2>This is a page to test the drop down</h2>
            <form method='POST' action="" id="dropdown">
                <select id="demo-htmlselect-basic" name="list">
                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">Part 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Part 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Part 3</option>
                </select>
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="submit"name="submit" id="submit"value="Submit"/>
            </form>
    </center>


<script type="text/javascript"src="//healtend.it/uploads/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="//healtend.it/uploads/jquery.ddslicksd.min.js"></script>
```